# Best tool for error reporting/logging from mobile app

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, mobile

Our mobile android app is now available for our testers to download n their own phones.

They get constant crashes though that we don't know how to fix because the app is no longer running in our local android studio where we can just see the error from Logcat.

Are there any tools that we can use in our project to maybe log the errors from our testers phone and save it or send it somewhere where we can see the stacktrace/log???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Firebase Crashlytics (earlier known as Fabric which was later bought by Google and now a part of Firebase). It is a free service that offers real time crash reporting and insights based on that.

[Link to Firebase Crashlytics Docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)

[Get started with Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android#nav-buttons-1)